# How to delete label of a form in Django

Tags: django

How can I delete label of form in Django. I have something like this.

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user_image']
        widgets = {
            'user_image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image-upload', 'label': ''}),
            
        }
```

image-upload class does not include label. I have a auto-generated label and is written 'user-image'

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it via init:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user_image']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_image'].label = ''
```